# lightning-datatable - remove header actions

Tags: javascript, css, lightning-web-components

Is it possible to remove the header (column) actions completely from [`lightning-datatable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable)?

It seems that no matter what I do I'm still stuck with `Wrap Text` and `Clip Text` actions.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Adding more details as I see that my original question is about to be closed.

I've seen [some solutions](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005emkQAA) that worked with `lightning:datatable` **aura** component that served the same purpose. However, in lightning **web** components, the parent component cannot affect the style of inner elements of its child components (see documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_components_css)). Nonetheless, I tried to apply the **aura** approach to the **web** component and failed (see [my playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/fqWQdkQYT/2/edit) and the below code snippet from `basic.css` file in the playground).

```
.myTable .slds-th__action .slds-th__action-button { display: none; }

.slds-button_icon-bare{
    display: none;
}
```

I also went through the [component documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation), but I cannot see any obvious way to hide these actions. Even tried setting the `actions` attribute on `columns` but that just adds additional actions below the `Wrap Text` and `Clip Text`:

```
const columns = [
    { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'name', 
        actions: [{ label: 'Dummy', checked: true, name:'all' }] }
];
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide code snippet?

Comment: There's really no special code to provide. If you follow the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) to the component the code for it is there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use **hideDefaultActions**. I tried and it worked for me.

[image]

Please refer **Working with Column Properties** in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation).

Proof below

[image]

Comment: It works for Summer'20 orgs.

Comment: If we use `hideDefaultActions: true`, then wrapping column text is not working.

Answer (score 8):

sadly this isn't currently available in the LWC version, as you've already discovered, due to web components not allowing you to reach into custom elements. In fact, you shouldn't do it in the Aura version either, as our DOM (markup) structure can change and/or the SLDS rules, which can change and thereby breaking your component.

We will be providing a way to remove the header column actions (and even remove the entire header row itself) in an upcoming release. (Forward looking statement, blah, blah, blah.)

Comment: I have been able to hide header actions. The key is have the css to hide loaded from separate css style sheet from loadScript. If you keep it in component css (self) then it doesn't work.

Comment: nice hack, Anshul!

Comment: Anshul, I love this solution. I am sorry that SFDC gives us components that we cannot modify and then tells us we shouldn't but seriously, in the docs for the LWC datatable it says you can hide the number column by omitting the call for it, and you cannot! So custom CSS bundle is perfect, just saved me on that! Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this in LWC you just need to add hideDefaultActions: true to each column when you declare those in the .js file, not to the  attributes in the .html file.

```js
const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true }
];
```

Comment: This isn't substantially different from 2 of the existing answers, so this answer may end up being deleted by the community.

Comment: this worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

There's a `hideDefaultActions` property in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) now, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work.

Comment: Not working for me either.

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: It works for Summer'20 orgs.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered a possible solution with appending style element. It's not ideal, but helps. This is a part of `myComponent.js`

```
// Rendered callback adds style element that hides standard action buttons
renderedCallback() {
    if (!this.hasRendered) {
        const style = document.createElement("style");

        // CSS rule. You have to replace "c-my-component" with your component name that contains lightning-datatable
        style.innerText =
            "c-my-component lightning-datatable .slds-th__action-button {display: none;}";
        this.template
            .querySelector("lightning-datatable")
            .appendChild(style);

        this.hasRendered = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem and tried renderedCallback but getting error 'Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null'

Comment: @bksfdc, did you query a component that directly uses `lightning-datatable`?

Comment: yes, I did. I replaced c-my-component with my component containing the data table but no luck

Comment: @bksfdc, sounds strange, because I have some projects with the same solution and it still work. Could you share the code?

Comment: For this to work, You have to replace 'c-my-component' with your component name.

Answer (score -2):

const COLUMNS = [{label : 'Account Name', fieldName : NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName, wrapText:true, hideDefaultActions:true, sortable:true},
{label : 'Rating', fieldName : RATING_FIELD.fieldApiName, wrapText:true, hideDefaultActions:true,  sortable : true}];

Refer above code.

You can add hideDefaultActions:true to hide the dropdown on your column. And you can also wrapText from here only.

Comment: This appears to have already been covered in a few answers from ~3 years ago, just with less information.